# Webpack configuration for React Native

Tags: react-native, webpack

I'm new to react-native. I want to implement webpack for my project. Can anyone suggest a sample webpack config file for react-native

Comment: you can find here the some doc https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-webpack/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one:

```js
global.__PLATFORM__ = process.env.RN_PLATFORM || 'ios';

module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: {
    index: [
      'react-native-webpack/clients/polyfills.js',
      `./index.${__PLATFORM__}.js`,
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: assetsPath,
    filename: `[name].${__PLATFORM__}.bundle`,
    chunkFilename: '[name].chunk.js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 8081,
    quiet: false,
    noInfo: true,
    lazy: true,
    filename: `[name].${__PLATFORM__}.bundle`,
    watchOptions: {
      aggregateTimeout: 300,
      poll: 1000,
    },
    publicPath: '/',
    stats: { colors: true },
  },
};
```

Note that a Webpack config is not the only thing you'll need. [This guide](https://github.com/reactnativecn/react-native-webpack/blob/master/README.md) goes deeper and gives examples and explanations for the next steps:

2. Babel config
3. Module support
4. Assets require support